# Assign key value for auto increment field in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple pojo called `Books`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Books")
public class Books implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String author;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int isbn;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private double cost;

    public Books() {
    }

    public Books(Integer id, String title, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Books(String title, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
//getters / setters
```

Now, this is `Main` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BookService bookService = new BookService();
    Books book1 = new Books(1, "The Brothers Karamazov", "Fyodor Dostoevsky");
    Books book2 = new Books(2, "War and Peace", "Leo Tolstoy");
    Books book3 = new Books(3, "Pride and Prejudice", "Jane Austen");

    bookService.persist(book1);
    bookService.persist(book2);
    bookService.persist(book3);

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Will result as:

[image]

And if i re-run the `main` class, then the result is:

[image]

The `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` value is `update` .

I know since i have `@GeneratedValue` annotation, then i got another `id`, But why it does not displays an error for something like `assign Key Value for auto increment property` ?

Should i remove `setter` method of `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate while creating the auto increment id's create a pointer to the auto_increment value and gets the next id that can be used to save a new object and with this id the object is saved.

for example
When you save first object it gets auto_increment value as 1, it then uses 1 to save the object.
when you save second object it will get the auto_increment value as 2, it then uses this id to save the object.

[learn more about id generation strategies](http://www.ekiras.com/2014/08/hibernate-id-generation-strategies.html)

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` just updates the database if there are any schema based changes